# Calculate a field based on 2 calculated colums in SQL

Tags: sql, join, subquery, inner-join, calculated-columns

I have a query that sums a couple of values based on a common identifier known as a workcell.  I'm trying to figure out how to add a column that calculates this formula as a percentage: (SumOfAct - SumOfStd) / (SumOfStd)

I was thinking some kind of subquery with inner joins would work, but I'm not sure how to get it looking right.

Here is my code that gets everything I want except for that calculated column:

```
SELECT v_MES_OrderIssues.AssignedWorkcell
 , CONVERT(Decimal(10,2), Sum(v_SAP_OrderOperations.Std)) AS SumOfStd
 , CONVERT(Decimal(10,2), Sum(v_SAP_OrderOperations.Act)) AS SumOfAct
 , CONVERT(Decimal(10,2), Sum(v_SAP_OrderOperations.Variance)) AS SumOfVariance

FROM (v_SAP_OrderOperations 
LEFT JOIN v_SAP_Orders ON v_SAP_OrderOperations.Ordr = v_SAP_Orders.Ordr) 
LEFT JOIN v_MES_OrderIssues ON v_SAP_OrderOperations.Ordr = v_MES_OrderIssues.WOrder
WHERE (((v_SAP_Orders.OpenOrder) Like '1')
AND ((v_SAP_Orders.Equipment) Is Not NULL)
AND ((v_SAP_OrderOperations.ACT)>0))
AND ((v_MES_OrderIssues.AssignedWorkcell) Like 'S5H%W')
AND ((v_MES_OrderIssues.DateTimeClosed) Is Null)
OR (((v_SAP_Orders.OpenOrder) Like '1')
AND ((v_SAP_Orders.Equipment) Is Not NULL)
AND ((v_SAP_OrderOperations.OpenOp) Like '0'))
AND ((v_MES_OrderIssues.AssignedWorkcell) Like 'S5H%W')
AND ((v_MES_OrderIssues.DateTimeClosed) Is Null)

GROUP BY v_MES_OrderIssues.AssignedWorkcell

ORDER BY Sum(v_SAP_OrderOperations.Variance) DESC
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right yo can do it directly in SELECT clause

```
SELECT v_MES_OrderIssues.AssignedWorkcell
 , CONVERT(Decimal(10,2), Sum(v_SAP_OrderOperations.Std)) AS SumOfStd
 , CONVERT(Decimal(10,2), Sum(v_SAP_OrderOperations.Act)) AS SumOfAct
 , CONVERT(Decimal(10,2), Sum(v_SAP_OrderOperations.Variance)) AS SumOfVariance
 , CONVERT(Decimal(10,2), (Sum(v_SAP_OrderOperations.Act) - Sum(v_SAP_OrderOperations.Std))/ Sum(v_SAP_OrderOperations.Std)) AS percentage
...
```

BTW,

```
LEFT JOIN v_SAP_Orders 
...
WHERE (((v_SAP_Orders.OpenOrder) Like '1')
```

will be `INNER JOIN` really as a column from left-joined table expression is thus prohibited to have NULL value. You may wish to move the predicate to `ON` clause to keep it left-joined.

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't think it would be that easy!